# Awk to update value of column 2 basis value of column 9 and column 11 and 12

Tags: awk

I am using below code but getting wrong output. Could you please let me know what's wrong here.

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '{
**if((substr($9,0,2)=="02") && ($11="INV")) {$2="SAP_OSR_INV_FEB"}**
if((substr($9,0,2)=="03") && ($11="INV")) {$2="SAP_OSR_INV_MAR"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="04") && ($11="INV")) {$2="SAP_OSR_INV_APR"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="05") && ($11="INV")) {$2="SAP_OSR_INV_MAY"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="06") && ($11="INV")) {$2="SAP_OSR_INV_JUN"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="07") && ($11="INV")) {$2="SAP_OSR_INV_JUL"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="08") && ($11="INV")) {$2="SAP_OSR_INV_AUG"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="09") && ($11="INV")) {$2="SAP_OSR_INV_SEP"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="10") && ($11="INV")) {$2="SAP_OSR_INV_OCT"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="11") && ($11="INV")) {$2="SAP_OSR_INV_NOV"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="12") && ($11="INV")) {$2="SAP_OSR_INV_DEC"}
**if((substr($9,0,2)=="02") && ($12="EXPWT")) {$2="SAP_OSR_EXPORT_FEB"}**
if((substr($9,0,2)=="03") && ($12="EXPWT")) {$2="SAP_OSR_EXPORT_MAR"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="04") && ($12="EXPWT")) {$2="SAP_OSR_EXPORT_APR"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="05") && ($12="EXPWT")) {$2="SAP_OSR_EXPORT_MAY"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="06") && ($12="EXPWT")) {$2="SAP_OSR_EXPORT_JUN"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="07") && ($12="EXPWT")) {$2="SAP_OSR_EXPORT_JUL"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="08") && ($12="EXPWT")) {$2="SAP_OSR_EXPORT_AUG"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="09") && ($12="EXPWT")) {$2="SAP_OSR_EXPORT_SEP"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="10") && ($12="EXPWT")) {$2="SAP_OSR_EXPORT_OCT"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="11") && ($12="EXPWT")) {$2="SAP_OSR_EXPORT_NOV"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="12") && ($12="EXPWT")) {$2="SAP_OSR_EXPORT_DEC"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="02") && ($11="CR")) {$2="SAP_OSR_CR_FEB"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="03") && ($11="CR")) {$2="SAP_OSR_CR_MAR"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="04") && ($11="CR")) {$2="SAP_OSR_CR_APR"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="05") && ($11="CR")) {$2="SAP_OSR_CR_MAY"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="06") && ($11="CR")) {$2="SAP_OSR_CR_JUN"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="07") && ($11="CR")) {$2="SAP_OSR_CR_JUL"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="08") && ($11="CR")) {$2="SAP_OSR_CR_AUG"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="09") && ($11="CR")) {$2="SAP_OSR_CR_SEP"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="10") && ($11="CR")) {$2="SAP_OSR_CR_OCT"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="11") && ($11="CR")) {$2="SAP_OSR_CR_NOV"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="12") && ($12="CR")) {$2="SAP_OSR_CR_DEC"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="02") && $12="CAN") {$2="SAP_OSR_CAN_FEB"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="03") && $12="CAN") {$2="SAP_OSR_CAN_MAR"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="04") && $12="CAN") {$2="SAP_OSR_CAN_APR"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="05") && $12="CAN") {$2="SAP_OSR_CAN_MAY"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="06") && $12="CAN") {$2="SAP_OSR_CAN_JUN"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="07") && $12="CAN") {$2="SAP_OSR_CAN_JUL"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="08") && $12="CAN") {$2="SAP_OSR_CAN_AUG"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="09") && $12="CAN") {$2="SAP_OSR_CAN_SEP"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="10") && $12="CAN") {$2="SAP_OSR_CAN_OCT"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="11") && $12="CAN") {$2="SAP_OSR_CAN_NOV"}
if((substr($9,0,2)=="12") && $12="CAN") {$2="SAP_OSR_CAN_DEC"}}1' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

I want to update the column 2 value basis on first two digit of column 9 and value of column 11 and column12

Input file :

```
SAP||||||||022018|08AAACT2438A1ZT|INV|EXPWT|262881626|2018-02-02||||10||||TVH -COCO - VAISHALI|1151040011|8|08|08||||||9984|EVD0|EVD COCO CDMA Material|||0.00|8.47|0.00|0.00|9.00|0.76|9.00|0.76|||||||||||1301312397||ZEVD|1210|262881626|||||0
SAP||||||||022018|08AAACT2438A1ZT|INV|EXPWT|262881627|2018-02-02||||10||||TVH -COCO - VAISHALI|1151040011|8|08|08||||||9984|EVD0|EVD COCO CDMA Material|||0.00|8.47|0.00|0.00|9.00|0.76|9.00|0.76|||||||||||1301312569||ZEVD|1210|262881627|||||0
SAP||||||||022018|08AAACT2438A1ZT|INV|TAX|262881628|2018-02-02||||10||||TVH -COCO - VAISHALI|1151040011|8|08|08||||||9984|EVD0|EVD COCO CDMA Material|||0.00|8.47|0.00|0.00|9.00|0.76|9.00|0.76|||||||||||1301312574||ZEVD|1210|262881628|||||0
```

Current wrong ouptut.
Here in column 2 getting "SAP_OSR_CAN_FEB" which is wrong and also value in column 11 and column 12 also got updated with "CR" and "CAN" which is not supposed to be as want to update value in column 2 only

```
SAP|**SAP_OSR_CAN_FEB**|||||||022018|08AAACT2438A1ZT|**CR**|**CAN**|262881626|2018-02-02||||10||||TVH -COCO - VAISHALI|1151040011|8|08|08||||||9984|EVD0|EVD COCO CDMA Material|||0.00|8.47|0.00|0.00|9.00|0.76|9.00|0.76|||||||||||1301312397||ZEVD|1210|262881626|||||0
SAP|**SAP_OSR_CAN_FEB**|||||||022018|08AAACT2438A1ZT|**CR**|**CAN**|262881627|2018-02-02||||10||||TVH -COCO - VAISHALI|1151040011|8|08|08||||||9984|EVD0|EVD COCO CDMA Material|||0.00|8.47|0.00|0.00|9.00|0.76|9.00|0.76|||||||||||1301312569||ZEVD|1210|262881627|||||0
SAP|**SAP_OSR_CAN_FEB**|||||||022018|08AAACT2438A1ZT|**CR**|**CAN**|262881628|2018-02-02||||10||||TVH -COCO - VAISHALI|1151040011|8|08|08||||||9984|EVD0|EVD COCO CDMA Material|||0.00|8.47|0.00|0.00|9.00|0.76|9.00|0.76|||||||||||1301312574||ZEVD|1210|262881628|||||0
```

Expected correct output :

```
SAP|SAP_OSR_EXPORT_FEB|||||||022018|08AAACT2438A1ZT|INV|EXPWT|262881626|2018-02-02||||10||||TVH -COCO - VAISHALI|1151040011|8|08|08||||||9984|EVD0|EVD COCO CDMA Material|||0.00|8.47|0.00|0.00|9.00|0.76|9.00|0.76|||||||||||1301312397||ZEVD|1210|262881626|||||0
SAP|SAP_OSR_EXPORT_FEB|||||||022018|08AAACT2438A1ZT|INV|EXPWT|262881627|2018-02-02||||10||||TVH -COCO - VAISHALI|1151040011|8|08|08||||||9984|EVD0|EVD COCO CDMA Material|||0.00|8.47|0.00|0.00|9.00|0.76|9.00|0.76|||||||||||1301312569||ZEVD|1210|262881627|||||0
SAP|SAP_OSR_INV_FEB|||||||022018|08AAACT2438A1ZT|INV|TAX|262881628|2018-02-02||||10||||TVH -COCO - VAISHALI|1151040011|8|08|08||||||9984|EVD0|EVD COCO CDMA Material|||0.00|8.47|0.00|0.00|9.00|0.76|9.00|0.76|||||||||||1301312574||ZEVD|1210|262881628|||||0
```

condition to apply in short :

```
if ($11 ~ /^INV$) {$2="SAP_OSR_INV_FEB}  append FEB if first two digit of column 9 is 02 or MAR at end in column 2 if first two digit of column 9 is 03
if ($12 ~ /^EXPWT$) {$2="SAP_OSR_EXPORTS_FEB} append FEB if first two digit of column 9 is 02 or MAR at end in column 2 if first two digit of column 9 is 03
if ($11 ~ /^CR$) {$2="SAP_OSR_CR_FEB} append FEB if first two digit of column 9 is 02 or MAR at end in column 2 if first two digit of column 9 is 03
if ($12 ~ /^CAN$) {$2="SAP_OSR_CAN_FEB} append FEB if first two digit of column 9 is 02 or MAR at end in column 2 if first two digit of column 9 is 03
```

Comment: Because you did not put them as `else if` options, so all of them are evaluated

Comment: Do you do business in January?

Comment: You wrote code to call `substr($9,0,2)` about 50 times rather than calling it once and saving the result in a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My eyes are burning from that cut-n-paste programming.

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '
    BEGIN {
        mon["01"] = "JAN"; mon["04"] = "APR"; mon["07"] = "JUL"; mon["10"] = "OCT"
        mon["02"] = "FEB"; mon["05"] = "MAY"; mon["08"] = "AUG"; mon["11"] = "NOV"
        mon["03"] = "MAR"; mon["06"] = "JUN"; mon["09"] = "SEP"; mon["12"] = "DEC"
    }
    # criteria
    $11 == "INV"   { val = $11 }
    $12 == "EXPWT" { val = "EXPORT" }
    $11 == "CR"    { val = $11 }
    $12 == "CAN"   { val = $12 }
    # apply rules
    { $2 = "SAP_OSR_" val "_" mon[substr($9,0,2)] }
    1
' file
```

Note the order of the column 11 and column 12 checks: according to your "in short" criteria,

1. "CAN" in col 12 takes precedence over "CR" in col 11,
2. "CR" in col 11 takes precedence over "EXPWT" in col 12
3. "EXPWT" in col 12 takes precedence over "INV" in col 11

If those rules are not correct, you must be more precise with your criteria.

Comment: I laugh because if this was a C or C++ question, it probably would've been downvoted 5 or 6 times because the code would've made people so angry (despite being a perfectly legitimate question).

Comment: Ha, timely: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: 1 is for committing the changes we made..a way to print changes done

Comment: @Luis, it's explained quite nicely here: [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/). Also here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info

Comment: The BEGIN could just be `split("JAN FEB MAR...",mon,/ /)` and then access it with `mon[substr($9,1,2)+0]`. Btw awk strings (and arrays and fields) start at 1, not 0.